# Using Azure speech Text-To-Speech in Brwoser

Tags: azure-speech

I am looking out for examples on using Azure speech from within the browser.
I can see examples for Node.js but not for using Text-To-speech in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can find more information about how to use the text-to-speech capabilities from JavaScript here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-text-to-speech?tabs=script%2Cwindowsinstall&pivots=programming-language-javascript